# Show somebody to something

Tags: meaning

The verb "show" doesn't need any preposition. We show somebody something. So what does this structure mean:

> Show somebody to something

For example:

> They show me **to** a cent.

What I feel is it is an archaic form, conveys that the thing is a gift which be given to the first object. But I find no source which justifies my feeling.

Can anybody help?

This is the full stanza:

> I am satisfied—I see, dance, laugh, sing;
>
> As the hugging and loving bed-fellow sleeps at my side through the
>   night, and withdraws at the peep of the day with stealthy tread,
>
> Leaving me baskets cover’d with white towels swelling the house with
>   their plenty,
>
> Shall I postpone my acceptation and realization and scream at my eyes,
>
> That they turn from gazing after and down the road,
>
> And forthwith cipher and show me to a cent,
>
> Exactly the value of one and exactly the value of two, and which is
>   ahead?

Comment: Can you share some more context for this sentence? Does a "cent" refer to a one penny coin? Or to something else?

Comment: Is this from the Whitman poem, Song of Myself? In that case you have not included the full sentence, which is, "they ... show me to a cent, // Exactly the value of one and exactly the value of two, and which is ahead?"

Comment: It refers to one penny. My main context is a poem and many times when I put poetry here, users suggested that I have to go to literary stack exchange for such a question. So I decided not to put poetry here.

Comment: Yes the context is Song of Myself.

Comment: In poetry, you shouldn't count on capitalizations to show you where a new sentence begins. Here, Whitman capitalizes every line, regardless of whether a new sentence is starting or not. You have to observe the punctuation (period, question mark, etc) very carefully to see where sentences begin and end.

Comment: I know. But the beginning and end of the sentence is not the question. With the rest, my question still the question.

Comment: Yes, but by not including the whole sentence you make the meaning very unclear. If you recognized where the sentence began and ended, you should have included the whole thing (or enough of it to maintain the meaning), to make your question clear.

Comment: So if you want the real begging of this sentence you should go three lines up.

Comment: Yes, but you're right that the clause beginning with "they" can be analyzed separately from the rest of the sentence.

Comment: You know... that question mark at the end is in fact for a question which asked three lines earlier, and with your excerpt it does not make sense at all.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the question mark is for the question beginning with "shall I".

Comment: I think The Photon's answer is correct. That the phrase is in the middle of a longer sentence that is a question doesn't change the meaning in this case. Unrelated to the poem, note that the "show X to Y" structure also applies when an usher shows somebody to their seat.

Comment: Yes exactly. That is why I did not put it.

Comment: But you didn't show readers that 'the phrase is in the middle of a longer sentence' either, so it is unfair to ask people who don't know the poem (or even that the quote is supposed to be from a poem) for the sense you have in mind. ELU requires context, and not knowledge of lyrics, poems, films, history....

Comment: I explained. Every time I put the full excerpt of poetry, someone like you appeared and told me get out of here and go somewhere els. So please argue about this subject that whether poetry belongs to language or not, then announce your policy. Every day you or someone like you tell a new rule. If you don’t know the answer you can keep quiet and let others to say their opinions.

Comment: The rules for poetry are often very different from the rules for general English. This is called poetic licence, and this is why most questions about poetry are off topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the meaning of a phrase in a poem, not about general English.

Comment: The full stanza added. Now close whatever you like.

Comment: @CJDennis, the rules for poetry are often different from ordinary prose. But in this case the sentence would be perfectly grammatical (if a bit convoluted) in prose.

Comment: @ThePhoton It took me a hour and two answers (let's say 500 words on what the sentence means) for me to understand it, and I'm a native speaker! The grammar is so convoluted as to almost completely obscure the meaning. I think Whitman's trying to say "Two roads diverged in a wood" (Robert Frost). Did you _fully_ understand it on the first reading? If not enough native speakers can understand it quickly, that makes it a bad subject for a question here as I don't think rare/obscure meanings/grammar are on topic here or helpful to learn.

Comment: @CJDennis, I probably still don't fully understand the meaning, but I think I managed to parse the grammar without too much trouble.

Answer (score 6):

If this is from Whitman's poem, Song of Myself, the full clause in question is

> They ... show me to a cent,
>
> Exactly the value of one and exactly the value of two, and which is ahead

Here "to a cent" is telling how accuately they showed him the the value of things. The direct object (the thing being showed) is "the value of one and ... the value of two". The indirect object (the person seeing the thing being showed) is the narrator.

It means he wasn't shown the value very crudely (i.e. to the nearest dollar, for example), but very accurately, with less than a penny of uncertainty as to the value.

Some similar usages:

> Mr. Moneybags knew the value of his company to the dollar.
>
> The carpenter measured the length of the wall to the inch.

This is definition 5 of *to* at [Meriam-Webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to)

> 5. used as a function word (1) to indicate the extent or degree (as of completeness or accuracy)...

Comment: As you say the sentence should be like this in grammatical order: "They cipher and show me exactly the value of one and exactly the value of two to a cent." But I think it is wrong. The direct object is "a cent".

Comment: @Connoisseur, the thing that is being shown (the direct object) is "the value". "To a cent" is a modifier telling *how* it is being shown.

Comment: ok. Can you tell me what do you think about "one" and "two". What he means by "the value of one" and two? one what?

Comment: @Connoisseur, now that is a question of interpreting the poem, rather than simply one of grammar. It's for you as the reader to decide.

Comment: I am still not sure about your grammatical solution. But I like to know your interpretation.

Comment: It's one or two of anything. He is tempted to "scream at his eyes" because instead of "gazing down the road" they direct his attention to quantitative details like the "value of one and the value of two". (But I haven't read the whole poem)

Comment: I wonder how common "to **a** cent" is compared to "to **the** cent". I tried looking on Google ngrams but I couldn't find any parallel usages quickly. All your examples are with "to **the** X" which is the only way I've heard it before.

Comment: @ThePhoton, The word "to" could be kind of an archaic form. As in, "I could show you to a good time, if you're willing" It implies sort of grandly displaying the thing in question.

Comment: @Connoisseur, and maybe when he wrote "cent" he meant *hot dog*. But Occam's razor says it's more likely he used the words to mean the things the dictionary says they usually mean.

Comment: @ThePhoton, he used many archaism in Leaves of Grass, it is not a rare thing in Whitman's poetry.

Answer (score 3):

*Show* is a bitransitive verb. It isn't that it needs a preposition, exactly; the problem is that it has two objects. One is a person, an experiencer, the **audience**; and the other is what's being shown to the audience, the *show*. Prepositions are useful to mark them. For instance, the following two sentences are both grammatical, and both mean the same thing:

- *He showed her the car.*
- *He showed the car to her.*

Which one to use is up to the speaker, who may prefer either order of objects, or might like one extra, or one fewer, syllables.

There is another idiom with *show* and *to*, however, which is merely transitive; it means to guide a person (typically a guest) to a particular location. It takes a personal noun phrase as object and a prepositional phrase with *to* and a locational noun phrase.

- *He showed her to the Observatory.*
- *He showed her to the car.*

The last sentence means that he guided her (in person) to the location of the car.

Comment: This doesn't address the usage being asked about, where "to a cent" indicates in how much detail the thing (the "value of one") is being shown.

Comment: Outside an imaginary context, *_She showed me to a cent_ is ungrammatical without a final object for _show_, which is still bitransitive and requires a direct as well as an indirect object.

Comment: It's from a Whitman poem that's easily found online. There is an object in the original, but OP didn't include the full context in their post.

Comment: The full stanza added.